# Executing Multiple Actions

Tags: xpages

When adding a group of actions to an event on an XPage (e.g. Button onClick()), is there any mechanism to control if subsequent actions should occur based upon the result of a previous action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning `false` from any action automatically cancels the rest of the sequence.

Comment: I have "Execute Script" followed by "Save Document" in a button. querySaveDocument event gets fired regardless of what I return from the SSJS. When I remove "Save Document" the event does not get fired. I haven't found a way to cancel the save. If I save from the SSJS the event does not get executed so it looks like I need to use "Save Document" action.

Comment: Solved by this snippet: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=save-datasource-fire-querysavepostsave-events

Answer (score 1):

You can edit Action Group by selecting this Action Group in Events tab and pressing 'Edit' button.
Then add any conditional code (Server Side JavaScript, Expression Language or Custom) to the 
Action Group.

Action Group action executes a group of simple actions when the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is to encapsulate your logic into Java code and call single method to execute the action.

If you want it with groups, there is an option to set/read requestScope variable and according to its value branch your event handler. Not recommended.

Comment: The scenario involves calling a method in a bean followed by a simple action to move to a mobile application page. Experience has told me to avoid trying to implement MoveTo by any means other than a simple action can lead to a whole bunch of unwanted side effects.

Comment: That can be last statement executed only if return value of your Java method says so.

Comment: And according to experience: simple actions are nothing but Java code. Look into ExtLib sources what is behind that simple action...